# Cannot view public pages after being authenticated in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Why is that I cannot view the welcome page once I'm authenticated?

In other words if I try to view the welcome page once I logged in I get the following error...

> FatalErrorException in/Users/UserName/code/projectName/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/AliasLoader.php
>   line 63:
>           Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!

This is what I did, and I think what I did in step 4 is what is causing the issue.

1. Created new project
2. Ran php artisan make:auth
3. Created DB, migrated etc (DB works fine)
4. Moved the default route for the welcome page to be in an authenticated controller I created (PagesController)

Moved default route...

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
});
```

to be in...

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/' , 'PagesController@welcome');
```

PublicController

```
class PagesController extends Controller
{
            public function welcome()
            {
                return view('welcome');
            }
}
```

Any idea why?

FYI - If I move everything back to the defaults, I can see the welcome page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this row to your public/index.php file:

```
ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);
```

Comment: Placing `ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);` in the public/index.php file solved the issue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ Paul Androschuk - Excuse my ignorance but why this happened only on my local machine (Mac) and not on my remote server (Ubuntu)? In fact I don't even know what `xdebug` is and I'm not sure if I have it installed, I use PHPStorm as my editor and server my pages with `php artisan serve` on a Mac. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo or you handle `/` with `PagesController@welcome` instead of `PublicController@welcome`?

Comment: It's a typo, sorry

Comment: Your `PagesController` under `auth` middleware, am I right?

Comment: No I don't have middleware in PagesController. Thanks